# Running method from Controller in Artisan Command?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

In my custom Artisan command I fetch a list of items from my DB, I would like to iterate through them and run them through a method from my DownloaderController. How can I do this? and what is the best practise?

**DownloadCommand.php**

```
public function handle()
    {
        $files = File::all();

        foreach($files as $file)
        {
            // downloadFile method belongs to DownloadController
            downloadFile($file);
        }
    }
```

**DownloadController.php**

```
public function downloadFile($file)
{
    // some example logic to download file
    if(wget($file))
    {
        $file->status = 'Downloaded';
    }
    else
    {
        $file->status = 'Failed';
    }

    $file->save();
}
```

Comment: The right way would be move that logic to another class so that it would be able to call it from both Controller and Comand (controller and command display different ways of interacting with the app, but are on the same level, it would be wrong to call one from another one)

Comment: What if the downloadFile also updates the `$file` record? (check updated post)

Comment: then you pass that $file as a parameter to the class method. Like Filesaver::saveFile($file).

Comment: But should database changes be stored in that Class or in the Controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logic responsible for fetching data shouldn't be included in your controller. Create a repository (or a specialized service) for that, and inject it to your command.